# How do we arrive at the Bell polytope constructed starting from definition of behaviours?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bells-inequality, foundations

While reading *Valerio Scarani's* book ; *Bell Nonlocality*  I came across section 2.4 where the author tries to represent the set $\mathcal{L}$, of all local behaviours as a polytope. The term behavior is defined (Eqn 2.4 of the book) as the set $$\mathcal{P} = \{P(a,b\ |\ x,y)\}$$ where $P$ represents the probability of getting the output pair $(a,b)$ given the input pair $(x,y)$ in a Bell's Test / CHSH-like game. And the word Local has been used for any probability distribution where $$P(a,b\ |\ x,y)=P(a|x)P(b|y)$$ holds. If I understand correctly, $\mathcal{L}$ is a **set of sets**, the elements of $\mathcal{L}$ are not real numbers (they are sets of real numbers), hence the set $\mathcal{L}$ lacks well-ordering within it. The rest of the section (2.4.1) of the text talks about *convexity* of the set $\mathcal{L}$ and claims that the as the set $\mathcal{L}$ is the convex hull of it's extremal points, which brings me back to the same confusion. *What is a point within $\mathcal{L}\ ?$* I thought about considering the set $\mathcal{L}$ to contain the probabilities $P(a,b\ |\ x,y)$ directly as numbers (instead of being enclosed within sets). But that approach seems to cause more problems as two different behaviors might give different prescriptions of some given $P(a_1,b_1\ |\ x_1,y_1)$, then which prescription of this element shall we follow?

I feel like I am misunderstanding the very definition of the word "behavior" in this context. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT 1 - As per Section (2.4.1) of the aforementioned book, $\mathcal{L}$ is called convex because $\forall p\in[0,1]$ and for any choice of $\mathcal{P}_{LV,1}\in\mathcal{L}$ and  $\mathcal{P}_{LV,2}\in \mathcal{L}$ the convex sum  $\mathcal{P}=p \mathcal{P}_{LV,1}+(1-p)\mathcal{P}_{LV,2}$ also belongs to $\mathcal{L}$. I forgot to state this definition in the originl question.

Comment: "...claims that the as the set L is the convex...." What does this sentence mean?

Comment: @DanielFBest , I have edited the question appropriately so that the convexity of $\mathcal{L}$ is defined.

Comment: No, I mean about the grammar of the sentence. "...claims that the..." ...That the what?

Comment: Interesting question but I'm afraid it will be difficult to answer without being familiar with the book. Unless you copy the relevant definitions from the book

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give a precise answer without having read the book, but the correlations that you mention

$$
P(a,b|x,y)
$$

are usually called "boxes". The set of all possible boxes is perhaps what you are after. It is the set called $Q$ in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_nonlocality#:%7E:text=In%20theoretical%20physics%2C%20quantum%20nonlocality,a%20variety%20of%20physical%20assumptions.)

Comment: I understand from the link provided that we can view an observed behavior (also called a box) $\mathcal{P}={P(a,b | x,y)}$. But  $\mathcal{L}$ is a set of all such boxes. The wikipedia page says that we can view each behavior as a set of of vectors $(a,b,x,y)$, what I am having trouble in wrapping my head around is the fact the two different boxes that are included in $L$ may give different values of some $P(a,b | x,y)$, are we not losing that information when we make this map? Because as I understand it, our space is only spanned by the parameters, not the output probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

> If I understand correctly, $\mathcal{L}$
> is a set of sets, the elements of $\mathcal{L}$
> are not real numbers (they are sets of real numbers), hence the set $\mathcal{L}$
> lacks well-ordering within it.

You are correct, $\mathcal{L}$ is a set of sets of non-negative real numbers in a strict mathematical sense.  Of course there is no natural order in this set.

> What is a point within $\mathcal{L}$ ?

As we said every point is a set of numbers. For the purposes of this discussion is better to picture it as the set of conditional probabilities given a probability measure, that is keeping $P$ fixed. Or even better just consider every point as a probability measure $P$, i.e. one possible way to assigning probabilities to events. This is not exactly equivalent but I think the details are irrelevant for the current discussion.

> I feel like I am misunderstanding the very definition of the word "behavior" in this context

I think that for the purposes of this discussion is easier to think that a behavior is just a probability measure. Now given two probability measures, its convex sum is a probability measure. And the point of the discussion, as far as I remember, is that the convex sum of local behaviors, i.e. probability measures that fulfills your second equation, will be also a local behavior. That leads you to a polytope.